# Unable to scroll

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator

Please have a look at the following android xml file which is responsible for creating GUI

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/imageTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/imageDate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.34"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:text="@string/imageDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to scroll the whole screen, but it is not happening. The uploaded images will make it clear to you. Why it is not scrolling? I am new to android and this is my second app. Please help!
[image: Inside eclipse]
[image: Inside Android run]

Comment: use `wrap_content` for your LinearLayout

Comment: actually it takes wrap_content even if we give fill_parent i guess. Because in my app when i use fill_parent it asks to make it wrap_content which i haven't, still it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this 2 like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >  


<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/imageDescription" />
```

Answer (score 2):

for using scroll view, if u have entire view to be scrollable, use scroll view as parent layout and use code like this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

here  `android:fillViewport="true"` this is important part which allows u to fill the entire screen for your layout. if any other issue ask .

As android.developer says for fillViewport `Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use wrap_content in the LinearLayout